# Problem with curve / spline modeling, scale factor

Tags: bezier-curves, splines

I'm trying to taper a tube-like (beveled curve) object using another curve. Should be simple ...
But im always getting a strange 'scale factor' and I dont understand where it comes from.

The 'Curve' should be tapered exactly like the 'Taper' (top view). No 'scaling' in x- or y- direction. I watched many tutorials but they dont really help.

https://mega.nz/#!viwAyRCI!dNA4-x5LDpn3DYTxzF6Tf8_sg7DwlMmmQOUsIfaKfuI

Comment: Are you trying to make this type of shape result http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=70a324ee5edee6b0ba2f409bebeb717e if yes then i will proceed with the answer

Comment: Not really, i'm just trying to control the radius of the curve using the 'taper' curve. But its not following correctly. The bulges are not located at the right position (x position). It seems that the bulges come to early for some weird reason.

Comment: The scale seems to be based on the number of vertices (of each curve) not directly on the X position. Try to add a vertex somewhere in your beveled curve.

Comment: That sucks ... somehow whenever I try to use these curve features (bevel and taper) in blender, it doesnt behave properly and I end up finding another way ... If its based on the number of vertices its not usable. I will just use the screw modifier on the taper :) ... blender sucks in many aspects